# How do leaders cross the language barrier during phone calls?

Tags: international-relations, policy, languages, infrastructure

Recently, the American president spoke on the phone with leaders from around the world. Some are from English-speaking countries, but many are not, including Vladimir Putin. For such important and strategic negotiations, a human translator being present does not seem the most reliable - or convenient.

**What is the international standard for making these calls - who must learn what language, or otherwise what procedures occur, to allow direct phone negotiations to take place?**

Comment: Great question. I don't know the answer but will be interested to see what others say.

Answer (score 10):

Phone calls between world leaders are much more complicated and are thoroughly planned. It's not one would imagine -- pick up a phone and say `Hi President Putin! I'm Trump and I would like to talk to you!`.

In order to overcome language barriers, they have **human interpreters** and aides to assist them.

[This article by the BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-38202271) that I came across describes this process:

> World leaders **usually have various people listening in on their conversations, including aides and interpreters**.
>
> Even when leaders speak another language fluently, they often choose to conduct official calls in their mother tongue.
>
> "Sometimes that is down to national pride, but it's also to avoid misunderstandings and protect nuance," says Kevin Hendzel, a former White House linguist.

[This article by The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/jul/25/interpreters-world-events-gorbachev-reagan-deng-xiaoping-ahmadinejad) introduces 3 translators and their experiences.